# VBA "Block If without End If" Error on Worksheet Change

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that uses data validation to create dependent dropdowns for several of the cells that have specific values in a database.

Even with the dependent dropdowns a user can still enter an invalid combination if they change the first value after the dependent values have been selected.

I would like to clear the dependent cells anytime a change is made to the first dropdown. The first dropdowns are in column E and H. When E is changed I need to clear the contents in column G. When H is changed I need to clear the contents of columns K and O.

Here is the current code which produces an error:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next
If Target.Column = 5 Then
  If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   Target.Offset(0, 2).ClearContents
  Else
   If Target.Column = 8 Then
    If Target.Validation = 3 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Offset(0, 3).ClearContents
 Else
  If Target.Column = 8 Then
   If Target.Validation = 3 Then
    Application.EnableAnimationsEvents = False
     Target.Offset(0, 7).ClearContents
      End If
     End If
    End If
   End If
End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Exit Sub

End Sub
```

I have also tried to enter the Target.Asset as a range but I have not had the desirable results with that either.

Comment: It was unintentional.

Comment: You have 6 `if` and 5 `end if`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were using the correct indentation, you would notice a mismatched number of `If`'s and `End If`'s.
In addition, there were logic errors and invalid property names in the code.
Try this variant:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   On Error Resume Next
   If Target.Column = 5 Then
      If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
         Application.EnableEvents = False
         Target.Offset(0, 2).ClearContents
      End If
   ElseIf Target.Column = 8 Then
      If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
         Application.EnableEvents = False
         Target.Offset(0, 3).ClearContents
         Target.Offset(0, 7).ClearContents
      ' Else
      '  If Target.Column = 8 Then
      '     If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
      '        Application.EnableAnimationsEvents = False   'EnableAnimations ? or EnableEvents ?
      '     End If
      '  End If
      End If
   End If

exitHandler:
   Application.EnableEvents = True
'  Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Lines marked as commented out contain errors. This requires analysis.

Comment: This is perfect!